# Best way to explain why something failed

Tags: c#

Suppose I had the following method in an object:

```
public class foo
{
    public bool DoSomethingAwesome()
    {
        bool bar = DidSomething() //suppose this sends an email;
        return bar;
    }

}
```

If I wanted to provide more detail on why DidSomething returned a false would the best practice be to assign a message to a Property to foo, or assign an Out parameter to DoSomethingAwesome?

Comment: I think the question is a bit misleading, this is more about what to do in Error conditions (I vote throw Exception).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this depends highly on the framework you're using (i.e. it's a convention).

- For Win32 - you had the SetLastError,
  GetLastError.
- For .NET it's usually
  throwing an Exception but that could be
  changed to match your circumstances.

Probably an out param would be ok.

If you decide to go with the Exception route, MSDN has an entry with "[Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx)". And there's a great discussion in the book "[Framework Design Guidlines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)" - chapter 7, which I highly recommend!

Comment: Throwing an exception is the right way to go if it's all .NET.

Comment: I tend to agree, especially in this case because the action you're performing is likely not in a performance critical routine.  Exceptions are not the always the right solution but that is typically the case only with high-performance code because throwing/catching Exceptions tends to be slow.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on what you're doing, but in the situation given—sending an email—I would throw different exceptions based on what went wrong. As sending an email should work pretty much every time, when something bad happens, I'd want to force the caller to handle it rather than ignoring it by default.

In other situtations, where the chance of failure is high, failure can be ignored, or `false` doesn't necessarily mean failure, I'd create an `enum` which has values for each type of failure and one for success, and return that rather than a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer here:

[Handing exception in BLL and return to client (either winforms or webforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800161/handing-exception-in-bll-and-return-to-client-either-winforms-or-webforms/800202#800202)

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the false condition is not an "exception" (*not rarely but evenly occurs*) and then you should not use exceptions. In that case using an out parameter is much better.